# How to very quickly make a large table in python from a lot of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a table that has 500,000 lines or more, and I have used the tabulate module, but this takes much too long. I have a lot of lists with mostly numerical values in them, and I want to quickly make a large table.
Is there any module/easy way of doing this.

I know it takes too long because I can see that it doesn't complete the table quickly, and takes a ridiculous amount of time, possibly half an hour or even more.

say I had a 3 lists:

```
a=[3,4,5]
b=[7,12,3]
c=[9,20,34]
d=[]
d.append(a)
d.append(b)
d.append(c)
```

I could use the tabulate module to put them in a table:

```
print(tabulate(d))
```

This returns:

```
-  --  --
3   4   5
7  12   3
9  20  34
-  --  --
```

However, when you have 500,000 or more lists, the tabulate module is too slow.

How do you quickly make a table from a lot of lists?

Comment: You'll need to include some details, like a sample piece of code of what you are doing. Perhaps you can tell us how you determined it takes too long.

Comment: [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) ?

Comment: For some reason the question doesn't look like how I put it in???

Comment: I have formatted your question for you. Please look at the preview of the output before you post questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will remember that in future.

Comment: Can you change it off the [on hold] setting so people can answer?

Comment: `tabulate` is for pretty-printing. Are you trying to *print* 500,000 rows?

Comment: Are you sure it's a tabulate issue? Did you try writing to a file (or redirecting the standard output to a file stream). If your standard output is a terminal it'll probably be very slow. Also, what's the source of the rows? there might be an issue there too.